# $http post with angular gives error: possibly unhandled rejection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I've just managed to get my $http post working over Angular. It does what it needs to do, but when I post the data and then refresh the page it gives this error in my console:

Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/insert","data":

This is my Angular post call:

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.formModel = {};
  $scope.onSubmit = function(){
  $http.post('/insert', $scope.formModel)
  console.log('success');
  };
});
```

And this is my server call in Express.js to my MongoDB:

```
router.post('/insert', function(req, res, next){
  var item = {
    name: req.body.name,
    adress: req.body.adress,
    postal: req.body.postal,
    city: req.body.city,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    quotation: req.body.quotation,
    message: req.body.message
};

var data = new UserData(item);
data.save();
console.log('Item inserted');

});
```

Comment: `status":-1"` means possibly network issue..check the mongodb connection. also please tell `$scope.formModel` object

Comment: That seems not to be the issue because my data is successfully stored in the db

Comment: then you did not send back the status *200* after `.save()` just like `res.json(testObject);`

Comment: Yes, the status 200 did the trick. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
var BACKEND_URL = "http://whatever:port";
var postData = angular.toJson($scope.formModel, true);
$http.post(BACKEND_URL + '/insert', postData);
```

and on the backend, either use `res.sendStatus(200);` after mongo save operation or modify like below.

```
.save(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if(result) {
        res.json(result)
    }
})
```

Comment: res.sendStatus(200) was enough. That did the trick. Thanks for your help